# How does scala's actor model make use of C threads and native system threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, jvm-hotspot

How does scala's actor model make use of  C threads and native system threads?
I understand that the compiler is plugable , so a scala compiler replaces the java compilers.  I'm  confused by the next step,  doesn't the Intermediate Representation of the code just get optimised by the hotspot (possibly less effectively than the thread based model) and translated to a thread-based combination of  machine code and C.

Comment: This is a JVM implementation detail - nothing to do with either Java or Scala. They both use the `Thread` construct which is implemented in **native** code by the JVM.

Comment: Thanks Spider was the JVM implementation I'm interested in.

Comment: Which JVM? Which exact version of that JVM? On which exact platform?

Comment: The Java HotSpot Server VM ,Java SE 7 Update 60 running on Fedora 18 64 bit. Thanks for you help,  for now I  have enough to study using Vlads answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very rough picture of how native threads are used by Akka is as follows.

1. Akka [`Actor`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.6/index.html#akka.actor.Actor)s are objects instantiated by an [`ActorSystem`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.6/index.html#akka.actor.ActorSystem)
2. Then they are scheduled for execution on a [`Dispatcher`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.6/index.html#akka.dispatch.Dispatcher).
3. `Dispatcher` eventually delegates the execution to some [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).
4. Actual implementations of `Dispatcher` and `ExecutorService` determine the way JVM threads are created and used. By default a fork-join pool-based executor service is used. It is created with [`ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.6/index.html#akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator) which creates a factory which, in turn, creates corresponding implementation of `ExecutorService`.
5. Fork-join pool creates several [`Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)s internally and uses them to execute given tasks. The actual execution strategy is unimportant; there are other executors which can schedule tasks across threads differently, and Akka can be configured to use them instead of the default one.
6. `Thread` is a JVM-level abstraction which is implemented in the standard library. It uses bindings to native libraries (written in some native language like C++ or C) which delegate thread management to the OS.
7. So, when `Thread` object is created and started, eventually a native thread is created and started, and this thread will execute the code provided to this `Thread` object.

Here is a simple diagram of how actors are executed:

```
Actor -> Dispatcher -> ExecutorService ----> Thread --|                    |--> OS thread
                                        |--> Thread --|native code boundary|--> OS thread
                                        \--> Thread --|                    |--> OS thread
```

You can see that there are several layers of abstraction here. The most important one is `ExecutorService`: it completely defines the actual strategy for instantiation of threads and execution of tasks on these threads. It is possible to write a single-threaded executor service (in fact, there is one in the standard library) which will never spawn additional threads, and it is possible to force Akka to use it.

The intermediate representation (I presume you mean Java byte code) of actors *is not* optimized directly into a code which works with native threads because they are completely different levels of abstractions: actors are very high-level and provide numerous guarantees about execution order, while threads are very low-level and have to be used with extensive care if you want the program to be correct. Akka ensures that threads are used correctly, so you don't have to think about it yourself.

Comment: Very nice summary, +1.

Comment: I see this written often "Akka ensures that threads are used correctly" but how do we know this?

Comment: Well, that's because it is written so? I mean, that's the goals the library authors declare, and as of now it *does* work correctly, which is supported by numerous uses of Akka in production and in open-source software.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, actors are ultimately implemented using lower-level tools, such as `java.lang.Thread` (which will probably be implemented using native threads, though that's a JVM implementation detail), `synchronized`, and the various Java atomics.

The point is that actors provide a nicer API with guarantees that are easy to reason about; the system guarantees that a given actor will only process one message at a time, and will process messages in order, almost as if the whole actor were in a big `synchronized` block - but with much higher performance than if you did that. Anything you can achieve using actors, you *could* do "by hand", by having a bunch of locks, semaphores and the like, reading the Java Memory Model Specification closely, and very carefully writing your logic to ensure that all locks were acquired and released at the right time and every thread ran the task it was best suited to. But at that point you'd basically be writing your own actor system.

Comment: Point of order - synchronized is a completely different implementation & mechanism to the atomics & java.util.concurrent

Comment: Only sometimes. Per the spec, JVMs are allowed to use locking to implement the atomics, so they could be the same mechanism as synchronized. And even if the mechanism is different, they're often used to achieve the same results. What is the distinction you're trying to draw here?

Comment: They are completely different in the OpenJDK implementation, which is the vast majority of cases. Synchronized uses monitors. j.u.concurrent does not - it relies on mechanisms provided via Unsafe.